# Create a filtering function in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, filtering

I want to create a filtering function that trigger when receiving a input value event in react useState but i do not see is doing anything when I start typing in. This is my Search component

```
export function Search({categories, onSearch}){
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

    const filterCategories = () => {
        const filteredCategories = categories.filter(category =>
          category.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
        );
        onSearch(filteredCategories);
      };
    
      const handleInputChange = event => {
        setSearchText(event.target.value);
        filterCategories();
      };


    return (
        <div className="flex items-center"> 
        <form className='flex space-x-1' >
         <input 
                     type="text"
                     className="block w-full px-4 py-2 text-purple-700 bg-white border rounded-full focus:border-purple-400 focus:ring-purple-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-40"
                     placeholder="Search..."  
                     value={searchText}
                     onChange={handleInputChange}
                    />
       
        </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then is being used here

```
const Layout = ({ categories, children }) => {
  const [filteredCategories, setFilteredCategories] = useState(categories);

  const handleSearch = (filteredCategories) => {
    setFilteredCategories(filteredCategories);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <Search categories={categories} onSearch={handleSearch} />
      {/* ... */}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

and That goes into the Home component

```
export default function Home({ posts, categories }) {

  return (
    <Layout categories={categories}>
      <div className="mt-20">
        <main className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen pt-10 pb-30">
          {/* Render posts */}
        </main>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Is there anything I should do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `handleSearch` function passed as props `onSearch` to `Search` component expects an arg `filteredCategories` to set it to its state `filteredCategories`.

Now you are calling it each time you type in the input:

```js
onChange={handleInputChange}
```

what it does ?

```js
const filteredCategories = categories.filter(category => 
category.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));
onSearch(filteredCategories);
```

so you filtter based on `searchText` then you call `onSearch` passing the result of your filter i.e `filteredCategories`, however, this is not the correct approach since `searchText` won't be updated immediately but when the component rerenders (so you are a step late), therefore, you have to filter based on the input value not the state, in fact, with your implementation, you don't even need the `searchText` state at all:

```js
const handleInputChange = event => {
   filterCategories(event.target.value);
};

// ...

const filterCategories = (value) => {
const filteredCategories = categories.filter(category => 
category.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
onSearch(filterCategories)
}
```

Now you have the correct logic to update `filteredCategories` state in the parent component (`Layout`) and you should see the expected filtred data logged each time you type in the child component input causing the layout component to rerender:

```js
const Layout = ({ categories, children }) => {
  const [filteredCategories, setFilteredCategories] = useState(categories);
  console.log("function called: ", filteredCategories);
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Layout component you are passing `categories` value to your Search component, you probably meant to pass `filteredCategories`

```
const Layout = ({ categories, children }) => {
  const [filteredCategories, setFilteredCategories] = useState(categories);

  const handleSearch = (filteredCategories) => {
    setFilteredCategories(filteredCategories);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <Search
        categories={filteredCategories} // here
        onSearch={handleSearch}
      />
      {/* ... */}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

(`filteredCategories` was unused which made you feel that nothings was happening)